# What is the recommended way to set a global DNS server override on a system using systemd-resolved?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I would like my newer GNU/Linux system (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) to use a single, manually-configured, DNS server for *all* DNS queries. In the past, I could simply do `echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf` to clobber the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and persistently set the DNS server's IP address for my entire system.

On this (and many newer GNU/Linux distributions), `/etc/resolv.conf` is managed by the `resolvconf(8)` utilties. On Ubuntu 18.04, this file contains a line like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

As can see by `sudo ss --listening --numeric --processes`, the local system's [`systemd-resolved` DNS stub resolver](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved/) is bound to this IP address and is listening on port `53` for incoming DNS requests. Therefore, the above `nameserver` line in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is directing all applications that do not use `systemd-resolved`'s D-Bus or glibc API to the `systemd-resolved` service via "normal" DNS requests.

That's all fine and well, but all this means that I can no longer simply write persistent changes to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file in order to effect a nameserver change.

After reading [numerous](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd-resolve.1.html) [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html) [pages](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html) and [blog posts](https://stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/), I learned that I could set "global" DNS nameserver IP address(es) by editing, for example, the `/etc/systemd/resolve.conf` file such that this file contained a line as follows:

```
DNS=1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9
```

After making this change and invoking `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`, running `systemd-resolve --status` did show the new nameservers (`1.1.1.1` and `9.9.9.9`) in the "Global" section. However, a Wireshark packet capture confirmed that my system was still sending DNS queries to the "per-link" DNS server presumably configured via DHCP (say, `192.168.1.1`).

Further experimentation lead me to add the following line to my `/etc/systemd/resolve.conf` file:

```
Domains=~.
```

This seems to have successfully instructed `systemd-resolved` to *always* use the global nameservers (set in the `DNS=` option) and to *never* query any DHCP-supplied nameservers, even though those nameservers still show up when I inspect the output of `systemd-resolve --status`.

**Finally my questions:** Aside from the obvious impact this will have on, say, ignoring VPN-supplied DNS information, what other potential impact will this have on my system? And, more importantly, **is there a recommended way to completely override dynamically-configured nameserver settings, such as those provided by DHCP, on a system using `systemd-resolved` such as Ubuntu 18.04 that is more complete than simply editing each NetworkManager-managed connection via the GUI?** In particular, I do *not* want to have to edit the DNS settings for each individual Wi-Fi network that I join; I want *all* connections to automatically *always* use statically-configured nameservers for DNS resolution. What is the "best" way to do that, and why?

Thank you.

Comment: Does /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf refer to dnsmasq?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a recommended way, but here are a few options.

Disclaimer: all of this was tested on an Ubuntu 20.04 system, there may be some differences on other versions.

### Manual `/etc/resolv.conf` management

1. Create your own `resolv.conf`:

   ```
   echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv-manual.conf
   ```
2. Remove the systemd-resolved symlink and link to your own file:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
   sudo ln -s /etc/resolv-manual.conf /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
3. Verify your dns config is being used by issuing a query: `dig google.com`

Having `resolv.conf` be a symlink is importante because it gets overriden by NetworkManager otherwise.

Note that `resolvectl status` will still show the DHCP-provided DNS servers for the connection, and they may still be used by queries done through the dbus interface of resolved.

### Forced global DNS on resolved

You already had this one:

1. Create `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf`

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
   cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf
   [Resolve]
   DNS=192.168.35.1 fd7b:d0bd:7a6e::1
   Domains=~.
   EOF
   ```
2. Restart resolved: `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`
3. Verify with `resolvectl status`

You will still see the ISP-provided DNS server for the connection, but they will only be used for the domains listed under `DNS Domain:` in the `resolvectl status` output.

If you want to fully get rid of those DNS servers:

1. Tell NetworkManager not to set DNS servers for resolved:

   ```
   cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns.conf
   [main]
   dns=none
   systemd-resolved=false
   ```
2. Reload NetworkManager: `sudo systemctl reload NetworkManager.service`
3. resolved will remember the last DNS for the interface, so manually override them: `sudo systemd-resolve --interface=wlp3s0 --set-dns 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 5):

I miss the days when was easy to manage nameservers, just editing `/etc/resolv.conf`. While this actually still works, now distros like Ubuntu add services that symlink and manage `/etc/resolv.conf` replacing all setup I do.

Using ubuntu, I have a issue where my the `systemd-resolve` does not set the "Current DNS Server" from `nm` VPN configuration.
I'm using this to circumvent it.

```
sudo systemd-resolve --interface=ppp0 --set-dns=172.19.40.11
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are using NetworkManager, as it's Ubuntu.

To your first question. Unless you have the need for any non-global DNS, then I can't see any issue with setting a global DNS to a well-known, and stable DNS provider. Any change here will also be easily reversible.

systemd-resolved will on many systems have gained priority over `/etc/resolv.conf`, as you might see in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, `resolve` is probably before `dns`.

The resolve daemon will use the addresses from the `DNS=` setting in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, BUT will also use any server learned for an interface *in parallel* with the server from its `DNS=` option. Usually this is not an issue, as public DNS requests should either fail or return similarly useful results.

I don't know if there is a way to stop systemd-resolved from learning new DNS servers, but there might be ways to stop NetworkManager from installing them, e.g.

From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Unmanaged_/etc/resolv.conf:

In `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns.conf`, add or change:

```
[main]
dns=none
systemd-resolved=false
```

After various service restarts, systemd-resolved should have default DNS servers, and NetworkManager should ignore setting DNS. Give it a try.